# App Checking for updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am creating a update method for in house enterprise apps. What I am trying to create is a class that I can quickly put in a app and it will check with the server if it needs to be updated. This is what I have so far, it checks correctly but its returning `NO` before it finishes the method.

In my checkUpdate.h

```
@interface checkForUpdate : NSObject

+ (BOOL)updateCheck;


@end
```

In my checkUpdate.m

```
#import "checkForUpdate.h"

@implementation checkForUpdate

BOOL needsUpdate
NSDictionary *versionDict;


#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)


+ (BOOL)updateCheck {

    NSString *urlStringVersion = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://URL/app_info?app=app"];
    NSURL *urlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringVersion];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlVersion];

        if (data){
            NSError* error;
            NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            if (json != nil && [json count] != 0) {
                versionDict = [json objectAtIndex:0];

                CGFloat serverVersion = [[versionDict valueForKey:@"version"]floatValue];
                CGFloat appVersion = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey] floatValue];
                NSLog(@"Server Version %f",serverVersion);
                NSLog(@"App Version %f",appVersion);

                if ([versionDict count] != 0){
                    if (serverVersion > appVersion){
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
                        needsUpdate = YES;
                    }else{
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
                        needsUpdate = NO;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    });

    return needsUpdate;

}


@end
```

I call it like this

```
NSLog(@"Needs Update %@",[checkForUpdate checkForUpdateWithResponse] ? @"Yes":@"No");
```

This is my log

```
 Needs Update No
 Server Version 2.000000
 App Version 1.000000
```

I'm not sure why it's returning NO before it even checks. I need it to be a asynchronous because the server that the app will check with is behind our firewall. So if the person is outside the firewall the app needs to continue when is can't reach the server. I'm I headed in the right direction, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asynchronously checking for an update but expecting an immediate response by virtue of your method's design.  You can re-engineer your method to something like the example below to notify a handler whenever the operation is complete:

Note: Unchecked and untested for errors; however, the lesson to be gleaned from the example is to use a callback of sorts:

**UpdateChecker Class**

```
typedef void (^onComplete)(BOOL requiresUpdate);

@interface UpdateChecker : NSObject
-(void)checkForUpdates:(onComplete)completionHandler;
@end

@implementation UpdateChecker
-(void)checkForUpdates:(onComplete)completionHandler
{
    NSString *urlStringVersion = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://URL/app_info?app=app"];
    NSURL *urlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringVersion];
    dispatch_block_t executionBlock = 
    ^{
         /*
             Your update checking script here
             (Use the same logic you are currently using to retrieve the data using the url)
          */
         NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlVersion];
         BOOL requiresUpdate = NO; 
         if (data)
         { 
             ...
             ...
             ...
             requiresUpdate = ...; //<-whatever your outcome
         }

         //Then when completed, notify the handler (this is our callback)
         //Note: I typically call the handler on the main thread, but is not required.  
         //Suit to taste.
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
         ^{
             if (completionHandler!=NULL)
                 completionHandler(requiresUpdate);
         });
    };
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, executionBlock);
}
@end
```

**This is what it would look when you use UpdateChecker to check for updates throughout your app**

```
UpdateChecker *checker = [UpdateChecker alloc] init];
[checker checkForUpdates:^(BOOL requiresUpdate)
{
     if (requiresUpdate)
     {
        //Do something if your app requires update
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
     }
     else         
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}];
```

Comment: So this is a whole new thing to me, I'm just trying to get my head around this. Can you show me a little more how I would implement this?

Comment: Modified answer slightly to get you on track.  Notice the comment I added with regard to using your same logic.  Place all your logic at that spot.  I've included a small snippet of your code so you can get a better bearing.

Comment: In my second example, the code block you have supplied (the stuff between the curly brackets) will be called when your update checking has completed.  This is referred to as a callback, meaning, _let me know when you are done checking for my updates so I can do something about it_

Comment: Great thank you so much. I am pretty new to using dispatch. Any good tutorials or books that you know of on using dispatch?

Comment: There are quite a few.  I'll list the few that I found to be indespensable: [Intro to Grand Central Dispatch](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-28-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-i-basics-and-dispatch-queues.html), [Multithreading and Grand Central Dispatch on iOS for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial), and [a nice video presentation here](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2011/01/multi-core-ios-devices-are-coming-are.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since `dispatch_async` is non-blocking, your method returns before your update information has returned (does the dispatch and continues). As `needsUpdate` defaults to `NO`, that's what you'll see.  You can see this in your log timing - the "Needs Update No" shows up before the server and app versions.

You need some sort of callback (a delegate method or second `dispatch_async` for example) to ensure you get the correct result, or you need to block. I recommend looking into [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and [`sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) - it will execute the completion handler on completion, where you can have whatever code you need for handling the update.